# possible sets of output-preserving code manipulations

Tags: compression, operators

This is a theoretical question, so expect that many details here are not computable in practice or even in theory.

Let's say I have a string `s` that I want to compress. The result should be a self-extracting binary (can be x86 asm but can also be some other hypothetical Turing-complete low level language) which outputs `s`.

Now, we can easily iterate through all possible such binaries/programs, ordered by size. Let `B_s` be the sub-list of these binaries who output `s` (of course `B_s` is uncomputable).

As every set of positive integers must have a minimum, there must be a smallest program `b_min_s` in `B_s`

From `s`, I can also construct a canonical program `b_cano_s` which just outputs `s` in a trivial way. I.e. the size of `b_cano_s` will be in `O(#s)` -- if we think of [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) with data segments, we will even have `#b_cano_s ~ #s`.

Is there a set `A` of possible operations on the binaries which:

1 . Will preserve the output.

2a . Given `b_cano_s`, we can arrive somehow by operations from `A` at `b_min_s`.

(2b . Given `b_cano_s`, we can arrive at all programs in `B_s`.)

for all possible strings `s`.

The conditions 1+2a are weaker than the conditions 1+2b. Maybe, if there is such a set `A`, we will automatically have both, though. (Is that so?)

Does such a set `A` exists? I was thinking about some obvious operations, like searching for some repeated strings and shorten this. Or some of the other common compression methods. However, that probably is not enough to arrive at all programs `B_s` and my intention says also not necessarily at `b_min_s` for the same reason.

If it exists, can we express it, i.e. is it computable?

Answer (score 0):

You should link your related [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261685/what-is-the-maximum-theoretically-possible-compression-rate/3261692#3261692).

2a. As noted, you can not determine `b_min_s`, because that results in a paradox.  As a result, I don't think you can prove the operations in A are sufficient to reduce to it.

2b. You can brute force `B_s`, but this is an infinite set, and the procedure is non-terminating.  However, for each program in `B_s`, you can calculate a manipulation from `b_cano_s` to `B_s`.  However, that does not imply these possible operations will be meaningful.  It seems operations like "delete characters in this range", "insert character at this position" qualify.